# How to get rid of "i2c i2c-1: sendbytes: NAK bailout" errors on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 14.04, server, kernel, kms

After upgrading a 14.04 production server from 3.13 kernel to 4.4.0-112 it started producing these errors every couple of minutes:

```
[drm:drm_edid_block_valid [drm]] *ERROR* EDID checksum is invalid, remainder is 130
Raw EDID:
    00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
i2c i2c-1: sendbytes: NAK bailout.
i2c i2c-1: sendbytes: NAK bailout.
i2c i2c-1: sendbytes: NAK bailout.
i2c i2c-1: sendbytes: NAK bailout.
i2c i2c-1: sendbytes: NAK bailout.
i2c i2c-1: sendbytes: NAK bailout.
i2c i2c-1: sendbytes: NAK bailout.
```

How can I get rid of them? It doesn't have Xserver installed, obviously.

```
$ lsmod | grep kms
drm_kms_helper        151552  1 radeon
drm                   360448  4 ttm,drm_kms_helper,radeon
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, downgrading to `3.13.0-141` helped.